# Get in a python function the name of the caller function file

Tags: python

This code will print a message followed by `m1.py`, that's the file name obtained from calling `os.path.basename`. Instead, I need the `log` function to get the file name of the caller, in this case `m2.py` (that's the file that generates the log entry `'message'`). How to achieve that?

`m1.py`

```
   def log(message):
       print(message + ' ' + os.path.basename(__file__))
```

`m2.py`

```
   from m1 import log

   def func():
       log('some message')
   
   func()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use inspect module :

```
import  inspect

def log(message):
    frm = inspect.stack()[1].filename
    print('[%s] %s' % (frm, message))
```

Comment: this prints `[__main__] message` I need the file name

Comment: then get` __file__` or see updated answer